# How to set a default bib path where all the bib files can refer to it?

Tags: bibliographies, paths, overleaf

I have a problem when I have multiple bib files (i.e.,full.bib,article.bib,conf.bib,book.bib,me.bib; all the bib files are put into the bib folder), that is, every time I want to add bib files to my document, I will write as follows

```
\bibliography{bib/full,bib/article,bib/conf,bib/book,bib/me}
```

but it's annoying when I have many bib files.

My question is that,
should there be a simple way to write down `thebibliography` just as follows

```
 \bibliography{full,article,conf,book,me}
```

with a pre-defined path at the beginning of the document like

```
\bigliographypath{bib/}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This is a solution for Overleaf since the user specifically asked to get the `BIBINPUTS` working on Overleaf in the comments.)

You can set the `BIBINPUTS` variable on your Overleaf project, by adding a file named `latexmkrc` with the following line in it:

```
$ENV{'BIBINPUTS'}='./bib//:' . $ENV{'BIBINPUTS'};
```

and then add some text to your `.tex` file to trigger a recompile.

The idea is similar to changing `TEXINPUTS` so that your project can access `.sty`, `.bst`, `.cls` etc in a folder: https://www.overleaf.com/help/212

Comment: @WangyanLi Your file was named `latexmkrc.tex` – this is a special file to control the `latexmk` build tool options, so it should not have any file extensions. I've renamed it to `latexmkrc` in your project, and behold! The citations appear!

Comment: It works well before, but when I started a new project, it surprisely won't work, may I have your attention to this project, https://www.overleaf.com/5287941nxtwys, hope you can help me find the problem, which is much appreciated!

Comment: @WangyanLi You were writing `\bibliography` instead of `\bibliographystyle` :p

Comment: Yes, I found you corrected it for me, but the first `\cite{aoki1967optimization}` doesn't apper which is belonging to the `\bib\book.bib`, any problem with that?

Comment: Yes - `book.bib` is already present in the TEXMF tree (`jurabib`), so the engine looks to that file instead of yours. Hmm. The easiest way to solve this is to rename your bib e.g. to `books.bib` and point the `\bibliography` at that.

Comment: May I add another control command to the `latexmkrc` file? I followed your answer to https://www.overleaf.com/help/212, but when I add one more code (say, `$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./tex//:' . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}; 
`) to the original one, the output shows the document doesn't read the file placed in `tex` folder, see, https://www.overleaf.com/5287941nxtwys.

Comment: It looks like it's working just fine.

Comment: not exactly, the use of `IEEEtran.bst` is to hide `[Online]. Available...` . It's obvious that the output doesn't read the file `IEEEtran.bst`, if we move it outside the `tex` folder, things will be different, see, https://www.overleaf.com/5287941nxtwys

Comment: By setting `TEXINPUTS`, LaTeX can now see the custom `.sty`, `.cls` and `.bst` in your `tex` folder. _However_ for `bst` files, there's _another_ variable `BSTINPUTS` that takes precedence, so LaTeX uses the default `IEEEtran.bst` in the system tree! Solution? Set `BSTINPUTS` to your `tex` as well.

Comment: Problem solved,  you're a true genius. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

On a unix system (including macs) you can do this using the `BIBINPUTS` environment variable (sorry, but I have no idea how to do this on windows). For example, if you are using bash then put the following into your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
export BIBINPUTS="$HOME/bib"
```

This is assuming that your bib directory is `$HOME/bib`. If not then you need to replace this with the appropriate path.

Comment: Thx for you reply, but I can't get it, since I used Overleaf, and can't find `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` either. Can it be simplified to just write a default path like `\bigliographypath{bib/}` at the beginning?

Comment: @WangyanLi I am not sure you can change it during compilation. `graphicx` does some somersaults to enable this functionality, as I understand it, and people seem to think even using that isn't a great idea. (I use it constantly, but they are very likely right even so.)

Comment: @cfr Yes, the reason I came up with `\bigliographypath{bib/}` is motivated by the similar setting in `graphicx`, but, unfortunately, I have not yet found the similar command in `biblatex`, does it mean the my question is a dead end?

Comment: @WangyanLi you can change the environmental variable in your project via a `latexmkrc` file – I've added an answer on how to do this.