# Overleaf: Bibliography in a different folder

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf

I have a large Overleaf document with a lot of references. It's useful for us to separate them into a number of `.bib` files, and to store these in a separate folder, to keep the project easy to navigate. The desired file structure looks like:

```
.
├── bib
|   ├── bib1.bib
|   └── bib2.bib
└── main.tex
```

In `main.tex`, the relevant code is as follows:

```
\usepackage{cite} % Allows for ranges in citations
\usepackage{mciteplus}

\bibliography{bib/bib1,bib/bib2}
```

I have also tried other folder names (eg. `bibliography`), and other formats (eg. `\bibliography{./bib/bib1,./bib/bib2}`, but none work.

I have seen other users get this to work correctly (see [How to set a default bib path where all the bib files can refer to it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310365/how-to-set-a-default-bib-path-where-all-the-bib-files-can-refer-to-it)). Is there some syntax or setting I'm missing?

Comment: This is a question you should directly ask to Overleaf support.

Comment: This looks like it should work in principle. And indeed in a simple setup it works on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/jvvmstcbhcxf. It would be much easier to say anything useful if you could share a proper example document with us (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Thank you for your example - it seems as though the issue was with a custom bibliography style (although I thought I had checked this before submitting this question, it seems I was mistaken). Thanks!

Comment: The bibliography style should have no influence on whether or not BibTeX can find your `.bib` files, but if things a working now, I guess everything is fine.

Comment: What was the bug? What did you change to get this to work? I seem to be having a similar issue.